# AR Location based Iphone app error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, augmented-reality

I am in the process of creating an AR based location iphone app using https://github.com/markrickert/iPhone-AR-Toolkit

I have got these errors and do not know how to fix it. Please will someone help me. With a walkthrough and correct code

Link for image http://i60.tinypic.com/2i9p8c0.png

Comment: added #import "ARKit.h" thank you now  just getting these errors now anyway to fix it?   http://i57.tinypic.com/23s7r9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be trivial but just check whether you have imported the .h File??

```
#import "ARKit.h"
```

Answer (score -1):

"Use of undeclared identifier _arViewController". To fix that simply add a property `ARViewController    *arViewController;` to your @interface.

`@interface ScanmarksViewController() {
ARViewController    *_arViewController;
}
@end`

or

`@interface ScanmarksViewController() 
@property (strong, nonatomic) ARViewController *arViewController;
@end`

Whichever you prefer.

Comment: The error is on `ARViewController` **type**, not on the actual variable.

Comment: I have the demo app for the AR-Toolkit. If I comment out the variable I get the same errors http://i.imgur.com/NklJKzp.png I'm pretty new to iOS dev, so I'm no expert at all and don't know if declaring the variable on the header (as I can't see it on the screenshot) could still produce the same errors.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw the asker's comment with the new screenshot. Your answer is perfectly valid. (I can't remove my downvote without an edit on your anwer though :/ )